# Which Java API from the Azure SDK to delete a NetworkSecurityRule?

Tags: java, azure, security, networking, azure-sdk

I can't find the Java API from the Azure SDK to delete a `NetworkSecurityRule` resource.

The REST API is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/virtualnetwork/securityrules/delete).

I use this Maven dependency: `com.microsoft.azure:azure-mgmt-network:jar:1.31.0`

In my code I hold a reference to a `NetworkManager` instance and I have a collection of `NetworkSecurityRule` objects.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my test, we can use the following code. For more details, please refer to the [docuemnt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.management.network.networksecuritygroup.updatestages.withrule.withoutrule?view=azure-java-stable#com_microsoft_azure_management_network_NetworkSecurityGroup_UpdateStages_WithRule_withoutRule_String_)
1. create a service principal and assign Reader role for the sp.

```
az login
az account set --subscription "<your subscription id>"
# it will assign  Contributor to the sp at subscription level
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "mysample" --role  Contributor
```

[image]

2. code

```
public static void main(String[] args){
 String clientId = "your sp appId";
       String secret = "your sp password";
       String domain = "your tenant domain";
       ApplicationTokenCredentials credentials = new ApplicationTokenCredentials(clientId, domain, secret,
            AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
       Azure azure = AzureAzure.configure().withLogLevel(LogLevel.BASIC).authenticate(credentials)
            .withDefaultSubscription();

       NetworkSecurityGroup group = azure.networkSecurityGroups().getById(
            "your nsg resource id");

       for(String i : group.securityRules().keySet()){

            System.out.println(i);

       } 

       group.update().withoutRule.apply();
       group = azure.networkSecurityGroups().getById(
            "/subscriptions/e5b0fcfa-e859-43f3-8d84-5e5fe29f4c68/resourceGroups/testgroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/test0123");
       System.out.println(group.Name());
       for(String i : group.securityRules().keySet()){

            System.out.println(i);

       } 
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, here you remove all existing rules, but I would like to delete only several ones (SSH in particular), could you please point me to the right direction to do so?

Comment: @ChristopheBismuthc You can use ```group.update().withoutRule(<rule nane>).apply()``` to remove one rule : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.management.network.networksecuritygroup.updatestages.withrule.withoutrule?view=azure-java-stable#com_microsoft_azure_management_network_NetworkSecurityGroup_UpdateStages_WithRule_withoutRule_String_

Comment: I just got back to the project, your solution works like a charm, thank you very much Jim for really relevant help.